# computing quantiles across many probs in R data.table, for multiple columns together

Tags: r, data.table

```
DT = data.table(x=rep(c("b","a","c"),each=3), y=c(1,3,6), v=1:9)

# Desired output
rbind(cbind(id = "v", DT[x == "a", as.list(quantile(.SD, prob = c(0.05, .5, 0.95), na.rm = T)), by = x, .SDcols = c("v")]),
      cbind(id = "y", DT[x == "a", as.list(quantile(.SD, prob = c(0.05, .5, 0.95), na.rm = T)), by = x, .SDcols = c("y")]),

      cbind(id = "v", DT[x == "b", as.list(quantile(.SD, prob = c(0.05, .5, 0.95), na.rm = T)), by = x, .SDcols = c("v")]),
      cbind(id = "y", DT[x == "b", as.list(quantile(.SD, prob = c(0.05, .5, 0.95), na.rm = T)), by = x, .SDcols = c("y")]),
      cbind(id = "v", DT[x == "c", as.list(quantile(.SD, prob = c(0.05, .5, 0.95), na.rm = T)), by = x, .SDcols = c("v")]),
      cbind(id = "y", DT[x == "c", as.list(quantile(.SD, prob = c(0.05, .5, 0.95), na.rm = T)), by = x, .SDcols = c("y")])
)
#    id x  5% 50% 95%
# 1:  v a 4.1   5 5.9
# 2:  y a 1.2   3 5.7
# 3:  v b 1.1   2 2.9
# 4:  y b 1.2   3 5.7
# 5:  v c 7.1   8 8.9
# 6:  y c 1.2   3 5.7
```

How can I best achieve the above output on a very large dataset efficiently with data.table (a few GB in memory)?  I've tried this but it's not quite what I want

```
# not right, want all 3 percentiles on the same row, for x and then y:
out <- DT[ , lapply(.SD, quantile, prob = c(0.05, .5, 0.95), na.rm = T), .SDcols = c("v", "y"), keyby = "x"]
out
```

Then how can I get the output I want above, but with id spread across the columns, so that it becomes a 3 x 6 data.table. e.g. with columns v5% v50% v95% y5% y50% y95% with 3 rows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `melt/dcast` to achieve this:

```
dcast(melt(out[, p := rep(paste0(c(5, 50, 95), "%"), 3)], 
           c("p", "x"), 
           variable.name = "id"), 
      id + x ~ ...)[order(x, id)]
#    id x  5% 50% 95%
# 1:  v a 4.1   5 5.9
# 2:  y a 1.2   3 5.7
# 3:  v b 1.1   2 2.9
# 4:  y b 1.2   3 5.7
# 5:  v c 7.1   8 8.9
# 6:  y c 1.2   3 5.7
```

---

Another option without an intermediate result;

```
melt(DT[, v := as.numeric(v)], 
     "x",
     c("v", "y"),
     variable.name = "id")[, as.list(quantile(value, 
                                              prob = c(.05, .5, .95))), 
                           .(x, id)][order(x, id)]
#    x id  5% 50% 95%
# 1: a  v 4.1   5 5.9
# 2: a  y 1.2   3 5.7
# 3: b  v 1.1   2 2.9
# 4: b  y 1.2   3 5.7
# 5: c  v 7.1   8 8.9
# 6: c  y 1.2   3 5.7
```

*Note.* I transformed column `v` to `numeric` (from `int`) to avoid the nasty warning from `melt`.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm guessing there is no straightforward way to do it all in one hit in a data.table grouping query, (going from DT to the printed desired output), without these intermediate steps?

Comment: Updated my answer with another option

Comment: I like the second approach. Thanks

Comment: I really like the second approach!! but I'd like a side note. Using names = TRUE (default) in quantile is quite inefficient. You could add the names using setattr(x = .SD, name = "names", value = quantile_names) or using setnames(.SD, ...) in the last sentence and that would be 2-3 times fast.